# Display all dates for a multi-day "event"

Tags: 7, nodes

I have an "event" content type that can have multiple dates or repeating dates. Up until last week the node view of a repeating event would display all the dates for the event.

> Repeats every week every Friday until Fri Apr 27 2018.
>   Friday, April 6, 2018 - 10:00am to 11:00am
>   Friday, April 13, 2018 - 10:00am to 11:00am
>   Friday, April 20, 2018 - 10:00am to 11:00am
>   Friday, April 27, 2018 - 10:00am to 11:00am

Now it only displays the first date.

> Repeats every week every Friday until Fri Apr 27 2018.
>   Friday, April 6, 2018 - 10:00am to 11:00am

I don't know what change I made that caused this. I checked the date field settings and the field display settings against a recent backup, and everything is the same.

Do you have any idea?

EDIT: It's not a display issue, it's a data issue. Via `node_load()` I can see that only the first data is written to the database:

```
'field_reserved_time' => array(
    'und' => array(
      array(
        'value' => '2018-04-05 19:30:00',
        'value2' => '2018-04-05 20:30:00',
        'rrule' => 'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TH;UNTIL=20180427T065959Z;WKST=SU',
        'timezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
        'date_type' => 'datetime',
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

While previously it would write all dates to the db:

```
'field_reserved_time' => array(
    'und' => array(
      array(
        'value' => '2018-04-06 17:00:00',
        'value2' => '2018-04-06 18:00:00',
        'rrule' => 'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=FR;UNTIL=20180428T065959Z;WKST=SU',
        'timezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
        'date_type' => 'datetime',
      ),
      array(
        'value' => '2018-04-13 17:00:00',
        'value2' => '2018-04-13 18:00:00',
        'rrule' => 'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=FR;UNTIL=20180428T065959Z;WKST=SU',
        'timezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
        'date_type' => 'datetime',
      ),
      array(
        'value' => '2018-04-20 17:00:00',
        'value2' => '2018-04-20 18:00:00',
        'rrule' => 'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=FR;UNTIL=20180428T065959Z;WKST=SU',
        'timezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
        'date_type' => 'datetime',
      ),
      array(
        'value' => '2018-04-27 17:00:00',
        'value2' => '2018-04-27 18:00:00',
        'rrule' => 'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=FR;UNTIL=20180428T065959Z;WKST=SU',
        'timezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
        'date_type' => 'datetime',
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: when creating a new "event" node, is the field still allowing you to enter multiple days?

Comment: @longboardnode Yes, the form itself looks/behaves the same. The settings are the same. Could this be caused by the server OS, or the way the db is configured to store repeating date info?

Comment: are you using any date modules for the repeat functionality and if so, ahve you updated it recently?

Comment: Using Date API module, which is up-to-date. I've moved on from this by creating a new content type and new date field. I suspect this is a bug caused by migrating the site -- including this content type and date field -- from D6 to D7. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have removed the repeat date option for date field. Please check your content type, for repeat date you must have to enable repeat option of date field.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I checked all the settings. It's correct:  


[Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Co2I8uF.png)